# How can I add alias description to git commands

Tags: git, comments, config, alias, hint

Git has built-in description for native commands (see `stash`, `status`, `stripspace` in picture).

Can I add such description for my custom aliases (like `st` in picture)?

[image]

Comment: I don't know of any way to do that. `git help st` (in your case) is the best you can get.

Comment: This is actually being done by the completion code in your shell, not by Git itself.

Comment: @torek Good point. It is done by Git Bash. Amy idea where can I edit the hints?

Comment: @phd "help" just shows "'st' is aliased to 'status -sb'"

Comment: Find out which completion scripts you're using (there are different sets available) and whack on them. You're *probably* using the ones distributed with Git, which get installed somewhere (depending on system) as `git-completion.bash` or similar. These may use a Git configuration item, `completion.commands`.

Comment: @EgorChubarov As I said in the 1st comment, this is the best you can get without writing a lot of code for programmable completion.